# Error while using pointgrey camera

Tags: ros, roslaunch, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

I am using pointgrey camera. I have installed the pointgrey camera driver successfully. When I launch the camera node, I can see the following topics : /camera/camera_info , /camera/image_raw and /camera/image. But when I try to subscribe to camera/image topic, I am getting the following error.

*[ERROR] [1467135193.921150993]: Client [/Camera_Object_Detection] wants topic /camera/image to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743], but our version has [wfov_camera_msgs/WFOVImage/807d0db423ab5e1561cfeba09a10bc88]. Dropping connection.*

Can I know how to fix this ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238309/error-while-using-pointgrey-camera/) by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-29**:
You didn't post the error...

**Comment by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) on 2016-06-29**:
Oops, sorry. Have posted the error.
[ERROR] [1467135193.921150993]: Client [/Camera_Object_Detection] wants topic /camera/image to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743], but our version has [wfov_camera_msgs/WFOVImage/807d0db423ab5e1561cfeba09a10bc88]. Dropping co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is a message type mismatch. The subscriber node is looking for sensor_msgs/Image messages but the publishing node is sending out wfov_camera_msgs/WFOVImage messages. I've never heard of the second one so I assume it is a custom message for the publishing node. You'll either have to change the publisher/subscriber so that the message type is the same in both or see if there is some way to convert it.

[EDIT] After looking at wfov_camera_msgs/WFOVImage on github, the message contains a standard sensor_msgs/Image with some extra info. It should be simple enough to change the subscriber node to use the WFOVImage message and just extract the regular sensor_msgs/Image.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) on 2016-06-29**:
yes, true.. thank you :) I changed the data type and the error got eliminated.